# How to deal with poles at the boundaries of integration

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

How can one evaluate this integral with poles at boundaries?

$$I = \int_0^a \frac{r^n}{r^{1/2}(a-r)^{1/2}}dr$$, $$n=0,1,2,\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

So generalising the integral we have
$$I_n = \int_0^a \frac{r^n}{r^{1/2}(a-r)^{1/2}}dr=\int_0^a r^{n-\frac12}(a-r)^{-\frac12}dr$$
Then by using integration by parts we get
$$I_n=2(n-\frac12)\int_0^ar^{n-\frac32}(a-r)^\frac12dr$$
$$=(2n-1)\int_0^ar^{n-\frac32}(a-r)(a-r)^{-\frac12}dr$$
$$=a(2n-1)\int_0^ar^{n-\frac32}(a-r)^{-\frac12}dr-(2n-1)\int_0^ar^{n-\frac12}(a-r)^{-\frac12}dr$$
$$=a(2n-1)I_{n-1}-(2n-1)I_n$$
$$\therefore I_n=a\bigg(\frac{2n-1}{2n}\bigg)I_{n-1}$$
To solve for a base case we can find $I_0$ by using the substitution $r=a\sin^2{(\theta)}\to dr=2a\sin{(\theta)}\cos{(\theta)}d\theta$
$$I_0=\int_0^ar^{-\frac12}(a-r)^{-\frac12}dr=\int_0^\frac\pi2 \frac{2a\sin{(\theta)}\cos{(\theta)}}{\sqrt{a\sin^2{(\theta)}}\sqrt{a-a\sin^2{(\theta)}}}d\theta=\pi$$
for all $a\in\mathbb{C}$. Hence we can solve the recurrence relation to get
$$I_n=a\bigg(\frac{2n-1}{2n}\bigg)I_{n-1}$$
$$=a^2\bigg(\frac{2n-1}{2n}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{2n-3}{2n-2}\bigg)I_{n-2}$$
By continuing this pattern we eventually reach $I_0$ such that
$$I_n=a^n\frac{(2n-1)(2n-3)(2n-5)...(1)}{(2n)(2n-2)(2n-4)...(2)}I_0$$
But $I_0=\pi$ hence
$$\boxed{I_n=a^n\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\pi=\Big(\frac{a}4\Big)^n\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\pi}$$
where $n!!$ is the [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial).